# Why does Fluendo which I bought not work any more?

Tags: dvd, video-player, media, fluendo

I have bought the Fluendo DVD player software a while ago because it always was the only software capable of playing all the DVDs I had on my computer. But this program seems to have been quietly abandoned: Software center tells me "not available for your current Ubuntu version. Please contact your vendor for an update." However the info page for that software does not even show a vendor!
I find this very frustrating especially since some DVDs which have worked fine with Fluendo cannot be played with alternatives like SMPlayer or Xine any more. 
For me, another small detail that made Ubuntu worse. :(
Is there any other proper DVD player program which can properly handle all the various copy-protected DVDs out there, which all play fine on consumer DVD players or Windows computers with purchased player programs?

Comment: the vendor is fluendo www.fluendo.com.  They have a follow up player.

Comment: Thank you!
I wonder why Ubuntu is not able to provide that information on the package information page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Ubuntu Restricted Extras package.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If you are running Kubuntu or Xubuntu then install `kubuntu-restricted-extras` or `xubuntu-restricted-extras` instead.

And then run this script.

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Source: [Ubuntu Restricted Formats](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs)

Comment: Thank you - I had the package installed already, but running the script was necessary to make the DVD I tried play back. This DVD now not only plays but also shows the menus correctly with the Totem video player (SMPlayer and Xine play back the video but do not show the menus).